# How to approach unbalanced Model II and Model III analysis with some nested factors in R?

Tags: r, nested, lm

I have inherited a data set for analysis which, due to logistics and an abrupt end to the project fieldwork, is rather messy… it is *very* unbalanced!  I’m super lost on how to deal with it in R as I’ve only done balanced, Model I ANOVAs before.

This is a long series of questions for someone feeling extra patient and charitable!!  I'm not even sure if this kind of question is allowed on Stack Overflow, so please let me know if not and I'll delete it.

Here it goes…

The experimental design looks like this:

[image]

The factors are as follows:

[image]

I'm pretty unsure about my categorisation of distance in the table above...  any thoughts?

The questions I actually want to ask of the data are:

1. Is the variation in BD captured using a single pit per dipwell, or is it necessary to dig and sample from multiple pits at each site? (Essentially, this is a methodology question)

Only scrub has multiple pits, so I can only use the scrub land cover to answer this question.

2. Does land cover influence BD?
3. In the shrub land cover, does BD change with distance from the canal?

I would like to check what the model structure should be for my questions.  My guesses are:

Question 1 and 3: (using just the scrub data):

```
BD ~ ((transect/dipwell)*distance)/pit*depth
```

I’m almost 100% sure it’s wrong because I don’t know how to include distance properly.  Without distance I would have

```
BD~(transect/dipwell/pit)*depth.
```

How do you stick a non-nested factor in there?  Can you even??

Question 2 (using the whole dataframe):

```
BD~(landcover/transect/dipwell/pit)*depth)
```

Moving forward, to analyse the above I’m pretty sure the aov function is inappropriate because it only deals with balanced Model I situations.  So I thought I could use lm. I know this can be used for Model III situations, can it be used for Model II (i.e. Question 1 and 3)? However I have never used this function before, can someone direct me to a resource that can step me though the process?  Open to other suggestions.

I've been Googling solutions for a few days now, but it's such a specific case that I can't find what I need to get on track.

Thanks very much!